# Using a custom field default image in menu via functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, menu

I have a problem in custom field in menu, i want to show default image if image is not selected

NOTE: I want to know the funtions.php method not inside php page files.

Here is my code.

```
            if ($image) {
                $item->title .= '<div class="thumb wrapme "><img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" /></div>';
            }else{
                $item->title .= 'This Should show up in relevent menu not in all';
            }
```

Else not working properly

[image]

It shows to all menu items which is wrong.

Comment: Where exacly is this menu included, which menu do you want to change with functions.php? The default wordpress menu is customized?

Comment: yes that is custom menu created via walker method.  i followed this to add custom field in menu 

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/

Comment: So you need 'This Should show up in relevent menu not in all' to be the default image ?

Comment: Yes Sir, if is working with specific item but else printing everywhere

Comment: Note that "good day geeks" may be interpreted as an insult, especially where it has come from an internet stranger. You probably want to steer clear of that here, especially since we prefer technical writing anyway.

Comment: I added some code, but you may want it inside a override function which you can add to functions.php also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work with isset()?

Or do you need this inside a function.php override?

```
if (isset($image)) {
    $item->title .= '<div class="thumb wrapme "><img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" /></div>';
} else {
    $item->title .= '<div class="thumb wrapme "><img src="wp-content/folder/default-image-url.jpg" alt="Deafult image description" /></div>';
}
```

EDIT:

maybe:

```
if (isset($image['url'] && isset($image['alt'])) {
    $item->title .= '<div class="thumb wrapme "><img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" /></div>';
} else {
    $item->title .= '<div class="thumb wrapme "><img src="wp-content/folder/default-image-url.jpg" alt="Deafult image description" /></div>';
}
```

What happens?

EDIT:

Then just set the title instead of appending maybe.

```
if (isset($image['url'] && isset($image['alt'])) {
    $item->title = '<div class="thumb wrapme "><img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" /></div>';
} else {
    $item->title = '<div class="thumb wrapme "><img src="wp-content/folder/default-image-url.jpg" alt="Deafult image description" /></div>';
}
```

Comment: It solved half of my solution its calling up now in relevant block  but instead of calling once its repeating  many time in single block.

Comment: please post that code below your answer, I will try to check

Comment: its coming like this:

<img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="">
<img src="" alt="">

it should work once

Comment: I meant in you original answer:) But you may want to check for the url and alt tag

Comment: hey the second solution not working it still repeating items into one block

Comment: I i see, you are in a loop. Then possibly you can set the title with = instead of .= :) I cannot see all the code so its a patch solution

Comment: with = the menu got complete removed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215025/discussion-between-rustyjim-and-syedz).